# current_user method is returning nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, railstutorial.org

I'm following Michael Hartl's book: "Ruby on Rails Tutorial 3". I have reached section 8.4.1 where he says:

> newly logged in users are correctly remembered, as you can verify by
>   logging in, closing the browser, and checking that you’re still logged
>   in when you restart the sample application and revisit the sample
>   application.

when I go through these steps I'm not logged in i.e: I can log in but when I restart the browser and revisit the app I'm not logged in as it is supposed to be.(I'm using localhost:3000)

> If you want, you can even inspect the browser cookies to see the
>   result directly

This one, however, works. I can verify that the cookie is saved successfully.

I have gone through this chapter several times, making sure that I'm following the exact same steps but still no luck.

Also the test is **not red**, I can logout at any time. I really don't know what to do. I have been trying several things but no luck. Excuse me if this is  a simple question as I'm new to rails.

**Edit:** you can view the chapter here: [Rails tutorial 3](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out#sec-remember_me)

**Edit 2:**

By adding some more tests, I can find that the problem is that `current_user` is returning `nil` (note: the problem is in the cookies not in the sessions):

## session_helper.rb

```ruby
module SessionsHelper

  # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  # Remembers a user in a persistent session.
  def remember(user)
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  end

  def forget user
    user.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end
```

```
  # Returns the user corresponding to the remember token cookie.
  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end
```

```
  # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  # Logs out the current user.
  def log_out
    forget current_user
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end
end
```

## models/user.rb

```ruby
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :remember_token
  before_save { self.email.downcase! }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}
  Valid_email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: {maximum: 255},
                    format: {with: Valid_email_regex},
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  has_secure_password
  validates :password, length: {minimum: 6}

  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                              BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(:remember_token))
  end

  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end

  def authenticated?(remember_token)
    return false if remember_digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
  end
end
```

## session_controller

```
# logging in a user by email and logging them out
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in user
      params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Invalid email/password combination"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    log_out if logged_in?
    redirect_to root_url
  end

end
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1) The ONLY difference I can see with my own code, is in the models/user.rb 
in before_save I think you either do 
    { self.email.downcase } 
or 
    { email.downcase! }

With this, I could not reproduce your problem though. And I don't see how it could affect the log in persistence.

2) The code you posted has implemented the 'remember me'-checkbox from 8.5
So, when you signed up, did you check the checkbox?